# uvicorn working on PyCharm but on server not work

Tags: python, pycharm, fastapi

I'm running a FastAPI app in Python using uvicorn it is totally wrok, but when I upload the file in deta which is https://web.deta.sh/ I got message error

[image]

**and this is my import**

```
from typing import Union
import uvicorn
```

I work with last version of uvicron and try version 0.17.1 but nothing has changed

I appreciate your help

Comment: Have you tried`pip3 install uvicorn`?

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it didn't change

Comment: You do not need uvicorn to run on Deta.SH

Comment: Can you check your data dashboard? It should show you what the dependencies are. In the DETAILS section you can find **deps** For instance: ```deps:
anyio==3.6.1, fastapi==0.78.0, idna==3.3, pydantic==1.9.1, sniffio==1.2.0, starlette==0.19.1, typing_extensions==4.2.0```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your local and server environment differs. What you can do is:

```
# Needed for running locally
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

This will remove the need to import unicorn in Deta.

If this does not work for you, you can add unicorn to the requirements.txt

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I added the code you wrote, but nothing changed, and still, uvicorn is into requirements.txt, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Can you share requirements.txt?

Answer (score 0):

mustafa from deta here.

i recommend using Charlie V's suggestion in general as deta doesn't use `uvicorn` to run your code. also make sure to remove `uvicorn` from the top of your file

i usually skip adding `uvicorn` to my code altogether and use `uvicorn main:app ...`

now to the other problem, it seems like your code and micro are out of sync. to fix that, remove the deps from your requirements.txt file, run `deta deploy`, then add them back and run `deta deploy` again. this should fix the issue.

if you still have any issue, please create an issue on our github discussions page.